# SequenceEqual in Equals makes GetHashCode broken

Tags: c#, ienumerable, equals, gethashcode

**(1)** I know that `GetHashCode` must return the same number for two objects if they are equal.

**(2)** I also know that `SequenceEqual` compare each value of a `List`, and `Equals(list1, list2)` will return true only if `list1` and `list2` are the same instance.

So, consider this code :

```
public List<ClassB> SampleList { get; set; }
public string Str { get; set; }
protected bool Equals(Uncorrectable other)
{
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(this.SampleList, other.SampleList) && string.Equals(this.Str, other.Str);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) { return false; }
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) { return true; }
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) { return false; }
    return this.Equals((ClassA) obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked 
    { 
        return 
            ((this.SampleList != null ? this.SampleList.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^
            (this.Str != null ? this.Str.GetHashCode() : 0); 
    }
}
```

I really need this behavior(**(2)** using `SequenceEqual`) for `Equals`, mostly for unit testing : make this code `Assert.AreEqual(classA1, classA2)` working.

But some of my code is probably broken because in this case

```
int hash1 = new List<ClassB>().GetHashCode(); 
int hash2 = new List<ClassB>().GetHashCode();
```

`hash1` and `hash2` are not equal.

So in my `ClassA`, **(1)** is not respected.

What is the best solution :

1. Change `ClassA.Equals` method to use `Equals(this.SampleList, other.SampleList)` instead of `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(this.SampleList, other.SampleList)` and change all my tests
2. Create another `IEnumerable` implementation where the `Equals` overriding is like `SequenceEqual`
3. Modify `ClassA.GetHashCode` to call `GetHashCode` on all list items
4. Do nothing
5. Another one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't base your `GetHashCode` on the `SampleList`: you don't need to use all the fields/properties in the `GetHashCode()`.

For example:

```
unchecked 
{ 
    return 
        (this.Str != null ? this.Str.GetHashCode() : 0); 
}
```

or even better use only some information of the `SampleList`... The `Count` for example:

```
unchecked 
{ 
    return 
        ((this.SampleList != null ? this.SampleList.Count.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^
        (this.Str != null ? this.Str.GetHashCode() : 0); 
}
```

If you truly want, you can calculate the `GetHashCode()` on the *elements* of the `SampleList`.

Now, for the C# obfuscation code tournament, 2016 edition:

```
unchecked
{
    return
        (397 * (this.SampleList != null ? 
            this.SampleList.Aggregate(0, (old, curr) => 
                (old * 397) ^ (curr != null ? curr.GetHashCode() : 0)) : 
            0)
        ) ^
        (this.Str != null ? this.Str.GetHashCode() : 0);
}
```

(please don't write it that way... Use a `foreach` cycle)

Comment: So obvious now (Somewhere in my brain was the idea of that the reciprocal of **(1)** must be true).. If the ClassA is not designed to be in a big list (I will only have 10 differents instance of ClassA), and that I do not really need performance, do we agree that I can use the second solution (using length or some other field)?

Comment: @ZwoRmi Yes. Note that calculating the hash of a big `SampleList` could be very long in general... So for example you could even "cheat" and include in the hash only a fixed subset of it... `(this.SampleList.Count * 397) ^ this.SampleList.Take(5).Aggregate`

Comment: If you just ignore the list entirely the collision rate is likely to be *very* high, resulting in very poor performance of whatever is using the hash code.

Comment: @Servy It all depends on the number of other fields present. Clearly if the `SampleList` is the "meat" of the object, the ignoring it is very bad. If it is only one of many pieces, then even ignoring it won't cause too many problems.